# Get Timestamps of words (Speech-To-Text)

Tags: bash, speech-recognition, speech-to-text, pocketsphinx

i actually use Pocketsphinx for Speech-To-Text an audio file.
I use this command:

```
pocketsphinx_continuous -logfn /dev/null -infile audio.wav > text.txt
```

and i want to know if there is a way to get the timestamps of each word. Just like that:

```
startTime: 0.000s, endTime: 0.200s, word: hello
startTime: 0.250s, endTime: 0.500s, word: world
```

It's not necessary to me to use Pocketsphinx but i need a free and not limited way for Speech-To-Text an audio file on Linux.

Comment: You can add `-time yes`, it will print the times.

Comment: Thanks @NikolayShmyrev, It's working ! Please post it as answer as i can put it as correct answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @NikolayShmyrev,
The answer is simply to add `-time yes` to the command